# Printing an array to a file with each element of the array in a new line in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying the contents of an array into a file with each element of the array in a new line in the file.

```
IFS=$'\n'   
echo "${mtches[@]}" > sample1.txt
```

The content of mtches is "qwe" and " asd". But the `sample1.txt` file contains `qwe asd` in a single line. Why is it not taking IFS value into the picture?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You [should use `printf` instead of `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo):

```
printf "%s\n" "${mtches[@]}"
```

If `mtches` is empty that would still output one empty line. To account for that:

```
{ [ "${#mtches[@]}" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "${mtches[@]}"; } > file
```

---

In `bash` (and also POSIX shells), you often use [Positional Parameters array](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137571/38906) as`"$@"` instead of `"$*"`, unless you have a special reason. That's also true in shells that support [regular arrays, from man bash - section Arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-arrays):

> Any element of an array may be referenced using ${name[subscript]}.
>   The braces are required to avoid conflicts with the shell’s filename
>   expansion operators. If the subscript is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the word expands
>   to all members of the array name. These subscripts differ only when
>   the word appears within double quotes. If the word is double-quoted,
>   ${name[*]} expands to a single word with the value of each array
>   member separated by the first character of the IFS variable, and
>   ${name[@]} expands each element of name to a separate word. When there
>   are no array members, ${name[@]} expands to nothing. If the
>   double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the
>   first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original
>   word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last
>   part of the original word. This is analogous to the expansion of the
>   special parameters ‘@’ and ‘*’

Only use `"${array[*]}"` when you want join all array elements to a string.

Comment: How does that make a diference?

Comment: @Ashwin http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Answer (score 7):

You want to use `${mtches[*]}` instead.

When you use `"${mtches[@]}"`, it doesn't matter what the value of `$IFS` is, bash will split the array into multiple arguments. What you want is a single argument with each array element joined by `\n`. `${mtches[*]}` accomplishes this.

Also as a temporary way of setting `$IFS`, you can do:

```
( IFS=$'\n'; echo "${mtches[*]}" > sample1.txt )
```

Then you don't have to bother with setting it back.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02 <- POSIX reference (this does not apply only to bash).

Comment: Or use `printf`...

Answer (score 3):

Using *for*:

```
for each in "${alpha[@]}"
do
  echo "$each"
done
```

Using *history*; note this will fail if your values contain `!`:

```
history -p "${alpha[@]}"
```

Using *basename*; note this will fail if your values contain `/`:

```
basename -a "${alpha[@]}"
```

Using *shuf*; note that results might not come out in order:

```
shuf -e "${alpha[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ENTRY in ${ARRAY[@]}; do
    echo $ENTRY
done > outfile
```

Nice and readable and doesn't mean messing with IFS. It also means you can customise the handling of each line.

Comment: But wrong as you're using [`echo` which can't be used for arbitrary content](/q/65803) and [forgot to quote your variables](/q/171346). A slightly better version was already posted by StevenPenny