# sh + how to use array in sh script in order to print all values in array

Tags: shell, shell-script, array

I want to use **arrays** in my **sh** script.

My target is to create an array with the values `a b c` and print all values in the array.

I succeeded to print each array, but I failed to print all values in the array.

Following example:

**Set each value in arr**:

```
n=1
eval arr$n=a
n=2
eval arr$n=b
n=3
eval arr$n=c
```

**Print each value from arr**:

```
n=1
eval echo \$arr$n
a
n=2
eval echo \$arr$n
b
n=3
eval echo \$arr$n
c
```

Now I want to print all values in `$arr` and instead of `a b c` I get:

```
n="*"
eval echo \$arr$n
{*}*
```

The values should be `a b c`.

Comment: check this question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137566/array-in-unix-bourne-shell

Comment: When you are limited to /bin/sh try avoiding too much scripting.
How much colleagues will understand your eval-calls? You do want to go on vacation some day.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sh` does not support **array**, and your code does not create an array. It created three variable `arr1`, `arr2`, `arr3`.

To initialize an array element in a `ksh`-like shell, you must use syntax `array[index]=value`. To get all element in array, use `${array[*]}` or `${array[@]}`.

Try:

```
n=1
eval arr[$n]=a
n=2
eval arr[$n]=b
n=3
eval arr[$n]=c

n=1
eval echo \${arr[$n]}
n=2
eval echo \${arr[$n]}
n=3
eval echo \${arr[$n]}

n='*'

eval echo \${arr[$n]}
```

Comment: I must to use sh script ) I dont have ksh/bash ) on my box machine , so ksh isnt relevant sorry

Comment: `sh` does not support **array**!

Comment: Is   doing `eval echo \${arr[$n]}` not the same as doing  `${arr[$n]}` ?

Comment: It's different. `echo ${arr[$n]}` causes syntax error.

Comment: But you can use `arr[$n]=a` without `eval`.

Comment: @Scott: Yes, of course. I put the OP's code default, only change which cause problem.

Answer (score 45):

Little late, but I don't see the ideal `sh` answer here so I'll chime in. If you don't need subscripting, then `sh` effectively **does** support arrays. It just supports them as space separated strings. You can print the entire contents of them, "push" to them, or iterate through them just fine.

Here's a bit of sample code:

```
NAMES=""
NAMES="${NAMES} MYNAME"
NAMES="${NAMES} YOURNAME"
NAMES="${NAMES} THEIRNAME"

echo 'One at a time...'
for NAME in ${NAMES}; do
    echo ${NAME};
done

echo 'All together now!'
echo ${NAMES}
```

Which outputs:

```
One at a time...
MYNAME
YOURNAME
THEIRNAME
All together now!
MYNAME YOURNAME THEIRNAME
```

Now, I said it doesn't support sub-scripting, but with a little bit of `cut` magic and using the space as a proper delimiter, you can absolutely emulate that. If we add this to the bottom of our above example:

```
echo 'Get the second one'
echo ${NAMES} | cut -d' ' -f2

echo 'Add one more...'
NAMES="${NAMES} TOM"

echo 'Grab the third one'
echo ${NAMES} | cut -d' ' -f3
```

And run it, we get:

```
Get the second one
YOURNAME
Add one more...
Grab the third one
THEIRNAME
```

Which is what we'd expect!

However, a string with a space in it can cause an issue and will completely break the sub-scripting.

So, really the better statement is: Arrays are non-obvious in `sh` and handling arrays of strings with spaces is hard. If you don't need to do that (e.g., an array of host names you want to deploy to), then `sh` is still a fine tool for the job.

Comment: Wasn't able to reproduce the cut part as each elements are thrown in a new line instead of a space when echoing the variable

Comment: That my be due to the shell you're using. Can you share your script (shebang included) and shell version?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the correct answer is to find a different approach. 
Get a better shell, switch to some other scripting language (maybe perl or python),
or rethink your design. 
But, to get a list of the values of all the variables whose names begin with `arr`,
you can use

```
set | sed -n '/^arr[^=]*=/s///p'
```

This will list them on separate lines.  To get them all on one line, use

```
echo $(set | sed -n '/^arr[^=]*=/s///p')
```

Not that this will sort them in lexicographical order,
so `arr10` … `arr19` will appear between `arr1` and `arr2`. 
(The same thing happens if you have files named
`maih1`, `maih2`, …, `maih10`, …, `maih19`.) 
If you know in advance how many array elements you are going to have,
you can fix this by using leading zeroes;
e.g., `arr01`. `arr02`, …, will get you up to `99`.

P.S. The trick with `set | sed …` will fail
if any of the variables’ values contain newline(s).