# How can i make multiple-read?

Tags: shell-script

I can not give much explanation because my English is bad. The example of what I want to do is below;

This is an example.

try.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Enter the port:"
read ports
if [ ! -d "$ports" ]; then

mkdir -p /root/port$ports
echo "The folder was created for $ports"
wget -q www.example.com/example.tar.bz2
tar -xjf example.tar.bz2
su root -c "screen -A -m -d -S 'example$ports' ./example -RunningAsRootIsEvilAndIKnowThat"
echo "$ports started."
else
exit 0
fi
```

Putty;

```
root@ubuntu:~# sh try.sh
Enter the port: 4445, 4546
Created folder 'port4445'
Created folder 'port4546'
4445 started.
4546 started.
```

I need shell script, not bash.

Comment: at least, what's the current problem

Comment: No problem.I just want it to be plural. For the entered value, I want to repeat the given commands for those values.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549714/shell-script-how-can-i-make-multiple-read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script shows that you are using `#!/bin/sh` in shebang line. That might be an issue, since [some default shells dont support arrays.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137571/85039). An example of that would be `dash` on Ubuntu. In case where you absolutely must use default shell that cannot use arrays, see Stephane's answer in the link. Alternatively, one could take advantage of word splitting like so:

```
read -p "Enter ports(space separated):" ports
for port in $ports
do
       [ -d "/root/port$port" ] || mkdir -p "/root/port$port" && echo "Created /root/port$port"

done
```

On the other hand, if we could use a shell with more capabilities ( and in many cases an OS has more than one shell), it would be better to use an array for storing ports. General approach for that I would take when arrays are available ( `bash`, `ksh`, `mksh`,`zsh` shells ) is like this:

```
printf "Enter ports(space separated):"
read ports
arr=( $ports  )
```

Here we're taking advantage of having string , for example, `80 22 23` being split at spaces (known commonly as word splitting) and provide those individual values to array `arr`. This is far from ideal, but works.

If you can use bash, it's possible to take advantage of `read -a` to read all items as array, and then iterate over the values. For example:

```
bash-4.3$ read -p "Enter ports(space separated):" -a portsEnter ports(space separated):80 22 25
bash-4.3$ echo ${ports[0]}
80
bash-4.3$ echo ${ports[1]}
22
bash-4.3$ echo ${ports[2]}
25
```

Same approach could be used on `ksh` with `read -A`.

Then you could do something like this:

```
for port in ${ports[@]};
do
   [ -d "/root/port$port" ] || mkdir -p "/root/port$port" && echo "Created /root/port$port"
done
```

I am not familiar with `csh` so won't provide solution for that, but the general idea should be similar

Comment: I do not use Bash. I need shell script.

Comment: @MehmetCanErtanLastOfDead bash *is* a shell and is the default shell on many systems. If you need a specific shell language, you need to mention that in your question. On many systems, `sh` is actually `bash` in POSIX mode anyway.

Comment: @serg the OP seems to be on Ubuntu, so their `sh` is `dash`. You might want to add a solution without the arrays. Something like `for port in $ports` will actually work for space separated strings.

Comment: Answer edited, added example for basic bourne-like shell