# How to join elements of an array in POSIX delimited by a space?

Tags: bash, shell-script, array, posix

The following works in a Bash script:

```
PACKAGES=(
    'curl'
    'git'
    'htop'
    'mc'
    'tree'
    'vim'
)

apt --yes install ${PACKAGES[@]}
```

But how can I do the same in POSIX so that I can use it in a `#!/bin/sh` script?

Comment: /bin/sh can't be guaranteed to support arrays; https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137571/117549

Comment: Do you _need_ to use `/bin/sh`? i.e. is there some system with `apt` that doesn't have Bash as a mandatory install anyway? (I know it's `Essential` in Debian and Ubuntu, but I don't know if there's some system that has gotten rid of it.)

Comment: You don't want to join them with space here, you want to pass each element as separate argument to `apt` (not as one argument which contains the elements separated with space, which `apt` would consider as one package to install)

Answer (score 7):

In a POSIX `sh` shell, you have exactly one array: `$@` (the array of positional parameters, i.e. `$1`, `$2`, ...).  You set its values with `set`:

```
set -- curl git htop mc tree vim
```

or from the command line:

```
./myscript.sh curl git htop mc tree vim
```

Then,

```
apt --yes install "$@"
```

Quoting the expansion of `$@` makes the array expand to its *quoted* elements.  That is, if the `$@` array contains `a word` and `another word`, `"$@"` will expand to those *two* strings.  Not quoting `$@` will make it expand to the *four* strings `a`, `word`, `another` and `word`.  The unquoted behaviour depends on the contents of `$IFS`.

Note that in `bash` too, you'd like to double quote the `${PACKAGES[@]}` expansion:

```
apt --yes install "${PACKAGES[@]}"
```

Related: [Arrays in Unix Bourne Shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137566/arrays-in-unix-bourne-shell)

---

You don't *really* "join the elements with spaces" here though.  Yes, if you `echo` the values you'll get spaces between them, but it's the difference between

```
set -- a b c d
printf '>%s<\n' "$@"
```

which yields

```
>a<
>b<
>c<
>d<
```

(four separate arguments, which is what you want)

and

```
printf '>%s<' "$*"
```

which yields

```
>a b c d<
```

(one single argument with the elements *joined by spaces* (the first character of `$IFS`), which is not what you actually want to use with your `apt install` command)

Comment: "Always", unless it was modified. Some shells including `dash` import it from the environment if there, most other shells ignore a IFS environment variable for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Since what you have is package names, you could just store them in a simple string variable, if you want to use a standard shell. At least [according to Debian manuals](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debmake-doc/ch05.en.html#name-version), the package names can only contain the characters `-+.:~a-z0-9A-Z`, none of which is a glob character or whitespace.

So, this should be ok:

```
#!/bin/sh
packages="curl git htop ..."
IFS=" "                           # make sure there's nothing weird here
apt --yes install $packages       # no quotes!
```

If you're paranoid, add `set -f` to the start to disable file name globbing. That would leave only spaces as an issue, but I don't think any sane system would allow whitespace in package names.

Comment: Note that several shells including `dash` inherit `$IFS` from the environment, so here you'd want to also fix `$IFS` to SPC (like every time you use that split+glob operator)