# Escaping spaces in dash

Tags: text-processing, escape-characters, dash

I want to do something like this.

```
$ touch a\ b
$ cmd=cat\ a\ b
$ echo $cmd
cat a b
$cmd
cat: a: No such file or directory
cat: b: No such file or directory
```

There are problems with the spaces in the file `a b`. So I tried this.

```
$ cmd=cat\ a\\\ b
$ echo $cmd
cat a\ b
$ $cmd
cat: a\': No such file or directory
cat: b: No such file or directory
```

Which also fails. How do I make it so that when I run `$cmd` I cat `a b`?

Comment: See [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444949/65304) - for `dash` (which doesn't provide the `ksh`/`bash` array syntax) you should still be able to use the `$@` array as described here [Arrays in Unix Bourne Shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137571/65304)

Comment: Also, see [BashFAQ #50: "'m trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Short summary: don't store commands in variables, they're for data not code. For something like this, use a function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set -- cat "a b"

"$@"
```

This would run `cat` with the single argument `a b`.  The expansion of `"$@"` (including the double quotes!) would be a list of individually quoted positional parameters.  The positional parameters are set with `set`.

It's uncommon to include the command name in the list itself though. It would be more common to see

```
set -- "a b"

cat "$@"
```

or, if you want to keep the actual command name variable,

```
cmd=cat
set -- "a b"

"$cmd" "$@"
```

If you, in-between setting the filename operands and running the command, want to add more filenames or options to the command, simply modify `$@`:

```
cmd=cat
set -- "a b"

# later (adding more files to the end):
set -- "$@" "more files" "some glob here-"[0-9]

# later (adding an option at the front):
set -- -v "$@"

"$cmd" "$@"
```

Note that it becomes difficult to add to the front of `$@` if the command name is already there.  In that case you would have to temporary `shift` the command name off of `$@` into a separate variable, add the thing you want to add, and then add the command name again:

```
cmd=$1
shift
set -- "$cmd" -v "$@"
```

We usually want to use `set --` rather than just `set` to set the positional parameters.  The `--` stops the parser of command line options from detecting command line options past that point in the command line argument list.  Note that without `--`, it would be impossible to add the string `-v` at the front of `$@` with `set` as `set -v` does something quite different.

Related:

- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946)

Answer (score 1):

When you're using `echo $cmd` or `$cmd` unquoted, split+glob is invoked on the content of `$cmd`. That has nothing to do with what happens when you do `echo cat a b` where it's the shell's syntax interpretation that separates `cat`, `a` and `b` into different arguments to pass to `echo`.

The split part of split+glob is done based on the content of `$IFS` which by default contain SPC, so the words resulting of that splitting can never contain SPC. You'd need to use a different separator:

```
IFS=:  # split on :
set -o noglob # disable glob part

cmd='cat:a b'
printf '<%s>\n' $cmd # split+glob
$cmd # split+glob
```

Alternatively, instead of relying on split+glob, you could have `cmd` contain a shell command line (code in the shell language) and invoke `eval` to interpret that code:

```
cmd='cat "a b"'
eval "$cmd" # note the quotes to disable split+glob
```