# Problem with sh in my shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, zsh

I was going through the shell script book, but in the array section, I got stuck. when I declare the array and **run the script like**:

`sh hello.sh`

**it shows me the error, even in ZSH, is below:**

```
one.sh: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

**when I run** like this `./hello.sh`, it's working like a charm.

*This is the Script*

```
#!/bin/bash
myarr=(on two three four five)
echo "${myarr[1]}"
exit 0
```

**Note**: why the `sh` isn't working, please. I'm a newbie in the shell!

Comment: without the script we can just speculate about the reason

Comment: @RomeoNinov I didn't get you, what you mean! I'm confused between these two methods.

Comment: Show in the question the script itself

Comment: sorry for that, I just added the script, Have a look @RomeoNinov

Comment: note: you spelt `one` wrong.

Comment: Nothing in this question is about Linux, or specific to Linux.  One could hit this on FreeBSD, for example.  Also, several points have been raised (in answer comments rather than question comments, unfortunately) about the inconsistencies and ambiguities in the question.

Comment: Didn't spell "one" wrong. He spelt "on" correctly. And missed "zero" off the front, assuming this was to illustrate array indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is Bourne Shell (`sh`) do not support array (not in this way you want to use). So do not use `sh`, stay with `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, etc.

You can find more info in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137571/101265)

> The Bourne shell or the POSIX sh language specification don't support
>   arrays. Or rather they have only one array: the positional parameters
>   ($1, $2, $@, so one array per function as well).

And f run as `sh hello.sh` will be read by `sh` independently from shebang and current shell.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you solved my mind.

Comment: There are three things here I don't understand, and which may confuse those who see this later: (a) Why does a script called "hello.sh" report an error saying it came from "one.sh"? (b) When it shows the error "even in zsh", does that mean with zsh ./hello.txt (which should work), or with sh command but with the shebang now /bin/zsh? (c) The actual issue (not addressed) is that running a script with an explicit shell treats the intended shebang as a mere comment.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, the script can be named, renamed by OP on different ways so if its hello, one it does not matter. If run as `sh script` will be read by `sh` independently from shebang and current shell.

Comment: I understood all that, but it shows that the posted output did not come from the posted script, and three different shells were involved, and that the role (or otherwise) of the shebang was ignored.